# Autodesk Forge SDK (php) cannot fetchToken

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, autodesk, forge

I'm trying to create a simple web page by using **Forge PHP-SDK.** But this is very new to me. 
I followed Forge Autodesk tutorials (https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/basic-usage-forge-sdk-php) however form the STEP 1 code

```
    <?php

    require_once( 'vendor/autoload.php' );

    Autodesk\Auth\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()
        ->setClientId('t5mp8L1dSjWf6Z7iIAdkcKwx1bBvEnum')
        ->setClientSecret('Sb9c93618353f48f');

    $twoLeggedAuth = new Autodesk\Auth\OAuth2\TwoLeggedAuth();
    $twoLeggedAuth->setScopes(['bucket:read']);

    $twoLeggedAuth->fetchToken();

    $tokenInfo = [
        'applicationToken' => $twoLeggedAuth->getAccessToken(),
        'expiry'           => time() + $twoLeggedAuth->getExpiresIn(),
    ];
```

However, It always return **HTTP ERROR 500** every time and I don't know why. 
so I really need help/suggestions, please.

Comment: is path to autoload correct ? `require_once('/path/to/ForgeClient/autoload.php');`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm using Composer to install ForgeClient. 
More information if I remove this 

"$twoLeggedAuth->fetchToken();" 

from code I'll get 

Array ( [applicationToken] => [expiry] => 1581090898 ) 

from print_r( $tokenInfo );

So I think path to autoload.php is correct.